# Find the sum of $(2n+1)$ terms of the series $3-1+13-9+41-53+\cdots$

Tags: summation

I am unable to find any way whatsoever of beginning. Please help.

> $$3-1+13-9+41-53+\cdots$$

Comment: whats the rule of the terms of the sequence

Comment: I'm guessing it's $-[(-2)^i+1-2i]$, in which case you can just split the sum into three simpler sums, no?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your sequence is $\big(−[(−2)^i+1−2i]\big)_{n\in\mathbb{Z}^+}$ then your sum is $$\begin{align}\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}−[(−2)^i+1−2i]
&=-\left[\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}(-2)^i+\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}1-2i\right]\\
&=\underbrace{-\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}(-2)^i}_{\text{geometric series}}+\underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{2n+1}(2i-1)}_{\text{arithmetic series}}\\
&=-(-2)\left[\frac{1-(-2)^{2n+1}}{1-(-2)}\right]+\frac{2n+1}{2}[1+(2\cdot(2n+1)-1)]\\
&=2\left[\frac{1-(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot2^{2n+1}}{3}\right]+(2n+1)^2\\
&=\frac{2}{3}(1+2^{2n+1})+(2n+1)^2\\\end{align}$$

Let's check it for $n=2$. The sum of the first $5$ terms of the sequence is $47$. Plugging $n=2$ in, we get $\frac{2}{3}(1+2^{2\cdot2+1})+(2\cdot2+1)^2=47$ so we're done. What's this got to do with Linear Algebra though?